# Alternative to ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders

Tags: .net, provider

I'm applying provider model for some parts of my application. And I don't want to add System.Web assembly to my class library. Is there any way to instantiate provider without using ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders (System.Web.Configuration)
Thank you so much!

Comment: @Inuyasha: Yes, this is.

Comment: You can't use something from System.Web without adding the System.Web assembly.

Answer (score 3):

this question is really old, but I thought I would share my experience with this same issue, for any future finders of this question. you could quite easily implement your own, there are a few fancy automatic type resolving things that the system.web version uses with internal HTTP helpers, but you probably don't need those if you don't need the other aspects of the `System.Web.dll`

*rough example:*

```
public static void InstantiateProviders(ProviderSettingsCollection configProviders,
    ProviderCollection providers, Type providerType)
    {
        foreach (ProviderSettings providerSettings in configProviders)
            providers.Add(InstantiateProvider(providerSettings, providerType));
    }
```

*InstantiateProviderMethod:*

```
public static ProviderBase InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
    {
        ProviderBase providerBase;
        try
        {
            string typeName = providerSettings.Type == null ? null : providerSettings.Type.Trim();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeName))
                throw new ArgumentException("Provider has not type name.");
            Type type = GetType(typeName, "type", providerSettings, null, true);
            if (type.ContainsGenericParameters)
            {   //if it is generic, we need to make sure the generic types get populated before checking inheritance and invokation
                var genericTypes = providerType.GenericTypeArguments;
                type = type.MakeGenericType(genericTypes);
            }
            if (!providerType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("provider must implement from type", providerType.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                providerBase = (ProviderBase)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                NameValueCollection parameters = providerSettings.Parameters;
                NameValueCollection config = new NameValueCollection(parameters.Count, StringComparer.Ordinal);
                foreach (string index in parameters)
                    config[index] = parameters[index];
                providerBase.Initialize(providerSettings.Name, config);
            }
        }
        catch (exc)...
    return providerBase;
}
```

the `GetType` method in there is really just parsing the type and getting it (plus some error handling) - but thats really all you have to do. and then call it in your `Initialize(string name NameValueCollection config)` method in your `ProviderBase` implementation.